# R function to return start & end date of a time series ts() object?

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, forecasting

I have created a list of 300 time series.

Now I want to create a training sample(by holding out most recent 3 weeks) for each of the time series to build forecast models.
So I want to use window function to subset the time series to skip the most recent 3 weeks as shown below.

```
# Creating training data
train_ts<-lapply(ts_list, function(x){
  window(x,start=c(start_year,start_month),end=c(.....,.....))
}
)
```

But the problem is that the end date of each of the time series is different.

So to help me achieve this, is there a R function which will return the start and end values of a ts object?

I searched in this website by couldn't find a solution.
Thanks

Comment: As returned by `head(..., 1)` and `tail(..., 1)`?

Comment: @Pascal I tried but not working.

Comment: This code head(ts_list[[1]],1) as per your suggestion.

Comment: I see, you don't want the value, but the date. You have `start` and `end` functions for this purpose.

Comment: @Pascal Thanks that worked. If you can post this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example assuming weekly data:

```
x <- ts(rnorm(200), frequency=52)
endx <- end(x)
window(x, end=c(endx[1],endx[2]-3))
```

Of course, there are not actually 52 weeks in a year, but that is probably a complication that can be overlooked for most analyses.

Answer (score 4):

To get the starting and ending date of a `ts` object, use function `start` and `end`.

```
set.seed(42)

# ts object starting in Jan. 2013 and ending in Dec. 2013
x <- ts(rnorm(12), start = c(2013, 1), end = c(2013, 12), frequency = 12)

start(x)
# [1] 2013    1
end(x)
# [1] 2013   12
```